# How to read Hazelcast Topic messages from Server to Client?

Tags: java, hazelcast

I tried publishing messages from Server to Client using `ITopic` in `Hazelcast`. The client is not able to receive the messages. But when I publish message in Client, Server is able to read the message.

Can anyone give me a sample program of publishing topic messages from Server to Client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you properly registered a listener on client side as well? Feel free to share your implementation here. Also, check out the code samples repo here for related examples: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/distributed-topic